# How to Label parcels in Arcgis with label insertion point left align

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, autocad-map

Scenario: After labeling all parcels in Arcgis, using Maplex in a nice looking manner.

Need: When the programs labels, i need that the left insertion point of text to be on the left side and always inside polygon even if its overlaps in some cases when is impossible to avoid it because of high density.

This is needed because after this, i convert the labels in annotation and then exported in Autocad. But the problem is that when i check the topology in Autocad i have multiple centroids problems because the left side insertion point of the text is not within parcel all the times, bacause when Arcgis Labels it tries to calculate that the center of the label being always within parcels.

Comment: This is not a direct answer but it might work better if you have the Feature to Point tool.  After you convert your polygons to points with the inside box checked, you then label the point using Maplex's options.  Then you convert that to annotation.

Comment: But i don't want the label in a fixed position, i need to find the best position inside polygon.

Comment: Label positions wouldn't be fixed if using Maplex's user defined zones options. As for polygon labeling, you might play around with different settings like anchor points, label overrun, polygon boundary weight ranking etc.  There are so many combinations sometimes trial and error is best.  But ultimately you may have to do some manual editing of the annotation; that is the usual suggestion for dealing with the limits of autolabeling.

Comment: I tried all of those options,its inevitable to get a fully automated labeling, need some manual hands.